# Combine multiple \parencite with optional arguments

Tags: biblatex, citing

Is it possible to combine multiple biblatex citation commands with optional arguments?

Please consider the following example:

```
% I use this if I want to reference the whole referenced work    
\parencite{Author00}
% compiles to (Author, 2000) in my setup
    
% I use this if I want to reference a specific chapter in the referenced work    
\parencite[Chapter~0]{Author00}
% compiles to (Author, 2000, Chapter 0) in my setup
```

If I want to reference multiple works at once, that's easy enough with

```
\parencite{Author00,AnotherAuthor01}
% compiles to (Author, 2000; Another Author, 2001) in my setup
```

But what if I want to mix one reference with an optional argument and one without? Or reference two chapters in two different referenced works? What I'd like to see is something like:

> (Author, 2000; Another Author 2001, Chapter 1)

and

> (Author, 2000, Chapter 0; Another Author 2001, Chapter 1)

The following **does not** yield what I want (due to potentially applied auto-sorting of references):

```
\parencite[Chapter~0]{Author00,AnotherAuthor01}
% compiles to (Author, 2000; Another Author, 2001, Chapter 0) in my setup
% -> Note that the Chapter reference was supposed to belong to the first reference

\parencite[Chapter~0, Chapter~1]{Author00,AnotherAuthor01}
% compiles to (Author, 2000; Another Author, 2001, Chapter 0, Chapter 1) in my setup.
% The Chapter references do not "attach" to the respective reference
```

Am I missing anything in the way the biblatex commands work or do I need to use a more custom setup?

---

The following is an insufficient workaround:

```
\parencite[Chapter~0]{Author00}\parencite[Chapter~1]{AnotherAuthor01}
% compiles to (Author, 2000, Chapter 1)(Another Author, 2001, Chapter 1) in my setup.
% -> Note the interrupted brackets
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add a minimal but compilable example https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography. Which BiBLaTeX style are you using?

Comment: Thanks for providing the link! I was struggling to make a minimal example, given that there are quite some packages involved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple answer to my question. Here's the answer in case anyone else stumbles upon this. It's as easy as:

```
\parencites[Chapter~0]{Author00}[Chapter~1]{AnotherAuthor01}
```

and will compile to

> (Author, 2000, Chapter 0; Another Author, 2001, Chapter 1)